# facebook games policy change

Tags: facebook, policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook says my app will be impacted by breaking changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587728/facebook-says-my-app-will-be-impacted-by-breaking-changes)

Because of the policy changes that will be changed on december 5th (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/09/05/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) I have received a notice from facebook with the following alert:

Your desktop web game hosted primarily off Facebook currently accesses user connections when authenticating and/or requests additional permissions beyond age, email, and publishing permissions. This is no longer allowed per Facebook Platform Policy I.13a:

I have no idea what i'm doing that i'm not supposed to. I run an app on facebook (apps.facebook.com/...) so how can my app be "hosted primarily off Facebook.com" ?

So i have 2 questions. 
How can i make sure that my app is now up to date. The information in the mail is very limited, so i can only guess what i'm doing wrong.
Secondly: Is there any way to test that my app is now okay, since facebook will put restrictions on it on december 5th

Answer (score 0):

Does your app on Facebook (aka Canvas app), implement an iframe inside the iframe provided by apps.facebook.com ?

The iframe provided by Facebook has id="iframe_canvas".

If you implement an iframe of your own *inside* the FB iframe with id="iframe_canvas", then you might get this message.

You choices are to remove your iframe, or make sure you originate all your API calls from the FB iframe (not from your iframe).